# Formating Visual Studio Column Jump

Tags: visual-studio-code, char, format

I'd like to edit my Visual Studio Code.

When I write my symbols on my keyboard to VSC, they'll get written Column by Column on the current Row.
\ Line of Code + Column.
(Ln , Col )

**Extensions**: "[Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by)"

= to jump to a certain column.
However, when i like to jump to 'column 50', it will only jump to the >End of Line.

```
// Example
// Goal is to get a Hotkey to Jump to Column 50
// Activated Hotkey*
cout << "Hello World:" << endl;   // If i use my Hotkey i get to the Column 30, not 50. Picture is enhanced*

/* The end of line is here: 30. */
```

**Question:** How can I achieve my Jump
via the given Extension? (Any easy solution would be helpful).
I don't like to use the Ln, Col in Vsc, because clicking on the UI is for me over the time to slow.
I'd like to use f.e. Cmd + M to get to my "middle", So for me column 50.
Hence, i **don't like** to go to **Middle of my current Screenformat**.

**Additional prefered Question:** One way how i like to solve the issue is in C64 Style.
Is there any way to fill out the Visual Studio Code Screen by empty chars?
So as an Preset.
I know, that i can just copy & Paste.  Or write an empty script. But that doesn't seem convenient inside the Configuration. I tryed to find that now unsucessfully since 2 weeks..

The reason is for me, that i currently try to code more cleaner.
And to achieve that (I have read many Clean Code Books during school and Github), i just like to try **this time an historical approach** by setting my own column points/ marks. (Basic C64-menu wise)

Thank you in advance!
Sincerely

Edit: I have enhanced beforehand.

[image]
Edit2: I have tryed the Find and Transform Extension pointed by Mark. Thank you for your time!

When i press the given Hotkey, It does marks the previous chars. but it doesn't start at column 50.
It marks at end of line.
I only like to move the cursor to column 50 and surpress the end of line.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

does this key binding work

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i ctrl+m",  // or any other key binding
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "moveby.calculation",
    "args": {
      "charNrEx": "50"
    }
  }
```

Or use `Ctrl+G` and type `lineNr:charNr`

Comment: Sry for expressing myself inprecise.
I wrote in the Code Sample, that i have tryed using the keybinding. It does only work in the example until line of 30.
If the column is above 50, then it is as i have stated, possible to use the keybinding.
So far it will jump <50, to the max char on the line.

Comment: @ViEt Then you must have set some max char/line length of 30. On my system it places the cursor at position 50, you haven't shown the keybinding you used in the question

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I'll regard posting the proof, as mentioned.
It doesn't fix the problem. But good to see, that you have come to the same Modification.
Edit: lineNr:charNr doesn't fix the problem as well, as how i have stated above. I'd like to reach the point with a simple cmd+m.*

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of not fully understanding the question, if what you want to do is pad any line to the 50th column with spaces, you can try this approach.

1. Install the extension [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview)
2. Make this keybinding (or it could be a command):

```
{
  "key": "alt+q",                  // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    
    // this will select the current line, cursor can start anywhere on line
    "preCommands": ["cursorEnd", "cursorHomeSelect", "cursorHomeSelect"],
    
    "replace": [
      "$${",
        "const str = `${TM_CURRENT_LINE}`;",
        "let currentLength = str.length;",        // current line length
        "if (currentLength >= 49) return str;",   // do nothing

        // pad to whatever column you want
        "else return `${str.padEnd(49, ' ')}`;",  // pad with spaces
      "}$$"
    ],
    "restrictFind": "line",                       // only on lines with a cursor
    "postCommands": ["cursorRight"]               // just cancels the selection
  }
}
```

[image: pad line to 50th column with spaces]

It'll work on multiple lines too if each line has a cursor on it

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have copy pasted your code sample, but weirdly it does not jump to the given spot.

Comment: @ViEt It does nothing then? You installed the extension?  Using the latest version 4.1.1?  Anything reported in Output/Find and Transform?

Comment: Yes, I installed the extension. 
Nothing reported so far from the console.
So no error Message.

Comment: Do you have a conflicting keybinding?